# Proof of Homomorphism Property for $(n - k)\mod n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Pretty easy question probably: How do you prove that $\phi(k)=(n-k)\mod{n}$ satisfies the homomorphism property for the binary structures $\langle\mathbb{Z}_n,+\rangle$ and $\langle\mathbb{Z}_n,+\rangle$?

Comment: I'm trying to prove it's an isomorphism. What I have now is $\phi(j+k)=(n-(j+k)(\mod{n})=(n-j-k)(\mod{n})$. I don't know how the transition from this to $\phi(j)+\phi(k)$ would be justified. I've proved the 1-1 and onto parts.

Comment: I changed $<\mathbb{Z}_n,+>$ to $\langle\mathbb{Z}_n,+\rangle$.  That is standard usage.

Comment: For general groups, the map $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is not a homomorphism but for abelian groups it is. This is what you have here, written additively.

Comment: I'm new to LaTeX: How do you do those angle brackets?

Comment: `\langle \rangle`

Comment: @Mike105 : Your question was answered by Douglas S. Stones, but notice that you can find the answer by clicking on "edit" on your question and seeing what appears there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that for all $a$ and $b$, we have $\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$. So, to use number-theoretic terminology, you need to show that if $x\equiv -a\pmod{n}$ and $y\equiv -b\pmod{n}$, then $x+y\equiv -(a+b)\pmod{n}$.

Comment: Yes, working backwards worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: @André Nicolas, your answer could be improved by showing it how? As it is, you nearly restate the defining property of a homomorphism.